# Prestashop with Paypal IPN or Express Checkout?

Tags: paypal, prestashop, paypal-ipn, express-checkout

## What I have done

I read from [Paypal site](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) that IPN can be used to:

- Update their inventory.
- Email a purchase confirmation.
- Trigger order fulfillment.
- Enable download of digital media.
- Update their customer list.
- Email a shipping notification.
- Issue a refund.
- Update accounting-related information.

And [here](http://www.addons-modules.com/prestashop-tips/2011/05/prestashop-tips-how-to-setup-paypal-ipn-instant-payment-notification/) is a way to configure IPN for Prestashop. Also I saw this file(3rd link) in a Prestashop Github fork.

There is no IPN in main repository, 4th link.

I read that Prestashop is intented to be used with Express Checkout.

## My questions

1. Should I use Prestashop with IPN?
2. Where can I read how Express Checkout works with Prestashop?

Questions in case I should use IPN:

1. How to do the most basic setup of IPN within Prestashop?
2. What will this most basic setup do?

I can share only 2 links :(, 3rd and 4th link will not be here.